# Comprobar una columna en tres tablas distintas

Tags: php, mysql

Hola quiero consultar una misma columna que se llama igual en las tres tablas. La columna se llama `status`, es un campo `INT` y solo puede llevar un 1 o un 0. Quiero rastrear de las tres tablas la columna `status` sin en una de ellos hay un `0` mostrar un mensaje y si están todos con un `1` mostrar otro mensaje.

Aquí lo que estoy comprobando pero si éxito.

```
$todasLasnotificaciones = $mysqli->query("SELECT pre.status, men.status, new.status FROM presupuesto AS pre, mensajes AS men, news AS new");
  if($todas = $todasLasnotificaciones->fetch_array()){}

if ($todas['status'] == 1) {
        echo "todas vistas";
      }else {
        echo "tienes sin ver";
      }
```

Comment: Tienes que hacer un Join de las tablas primero. Ejemplo `SELECT * FROM presupuesto AS pre INNER JOIN mensajes AS men ON pre.id = men.id`

Comment: ¿Qué relación existe entre los registros de cada tabla? ¿Cómo podemos combinarlos?

Comment: Hola @DavidJP realmente no existe ninguna relación solo que se llamán del mismo modo. Lo que hace esa columna es a especie de notificación, si tiene un 0 es que aún no se a leido y si tiene un 1 es que está leida. Por eso quiero que revise todas, si están todas leidas pues que me diga (todo visto), si en las tras tablas hay un 0 pues que salga otra cosa, me hago explicar? gracias!

Comment: Hola @Alezco05 no entiendo la necesidad de hacer un INNER JOIN, si realmente no quiero compararlas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que estás buscando lo puedes conseguir con algo así:

```
SELECT (
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM presupuesto WHERE status=0
  )+(
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mensajes WHERE status=0
  )+(
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM news WHERE status=0
  ) status;
```

Dará un 0 si todas están están leídas y el número de pendientes hay alguna sin leer.

Si quieres que funcione al revés usa `SELECT NOT(subconsulta);`

Espero que sea lo que buscabas

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta y como tendría que hacer el ìf` para devolver la respuesta? tal como lo hacia en mi pregunta?

Comment: Justo al revés :) Tienes dos opciones: a) `if ($todas['status'] ==0)` o b) `SELECT NOT(subconsulta);` De hecho te estás calculando el número de notificaciones pendientes

Comment: Perfecto muchas gracias voy a probarlo!

Comment: Hola lo realizo así; `if ($todas['status'] == 0) {
        echo "tienes sin ver";
      }else {
        echo "todas vistas";
      }` pero me devuleve todo el rato el `0` @David JP

Comment: Será que no tienes ninguna notificación pendiente, ¿lo has comprobado?

Comment: SI lo he comprobado y esta todo en `1` @David JP

Comment: Fíjate en que has cambiado, además del `==0`, el orden de los elmentos `if` y `else`. Vamos, que un cambio ha compensado al otro y te has quedado como estabas. Deja el 0 y pon los `echo` como los tienes en la pregunta

Comment: Lo he puesto como lo tenia en la pregunta y sigue sucediendo lo mismo `if ($todas['status'] == 1) {
      echo "todas vistas";
    }else {
      echo "tienes sin ver";
    }` @David JP

Comment: Perfecto, ahora toca SOLAMENTE el 1, cámbialo por un 0 y te funcionará

Comment: Me sigue sucediendo lo mismo, no se que pasa?

Comment: Ok, tienes razón, no estaba definido el alias `status` en la consulta: fíjate en el cambio que he introducido justo al final

Comment: Ahora siii!!!! gracias, muchas gracias! ;)