# Como puedo hacer esta query en laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Hola como puedo hacer esta query en laravel.

```
  ("SELECT (
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM presupuesto WHERE status=0
  )+(
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mensajes WHERE status=0
  )+(
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM news WHERE status=0
  ) status;");
```

Estoy intentando en route, pero sin éxito:

```
$consultarTodas = DB::table('mensajes')->select(DB::raw('count(*) as total'))->where('status', 0)->get();
```

Pero no se como hacer aquí lo del '+'

Comment: No! lo que quiero recorrer esas tres tablas, en ellas hay una columna que se llama `status`, quiero recorrer las 3, por que si en cualquiera de ellas hay un solo `1` que tenga el status=1 mostrare un mensaje, si por lo contrario están todos en cero, muestro otro mensaje @BetaM

Comment: Es lo mismo que pregunte aqui, pero en este caso con laravel https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/355383/comprobar-una-columna-en-tres-tablas-distintas/355568?noredirect=1#comment640502_355568

Comment: exacto! al final en las columnas `status` solo puede haber 1 y 0, de hay querer comprobarlo @BetaM , sorry si no lo explique bien

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que haces con esa subconsulta es obtener un conteo por cada una de las 3 tablas inscritas basándonos en un criterio que estableces a través del `where` para filtrar en el conteo solo aquellos registros cuyo `status` sea igual a 0.

Si es así entonces en Laravel podemos:

- Crear un [modelo para cada tabla](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent#defining-models)
- Usar el [método `count()`](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent#retrieving-aggregates)
- Usamos el método `where()` y lo encadenamos a cada consulta
- Devolvemos la respuesta en una *estructura de clave => valor* donde la clave será la palabra *status* y el valor será la sumatoria de las 3 consultas como lo hace ahorita tu subconsulta

En el controller importamos el *namespace* de los 3 modelo invocados:

```
use Presupuesto;
use Mensaje;
use News;
```

Posterior dentro del método donde quieres construir la consulta, haces lo siguiente:

```
$consulta1 = Presupuesto::whereStatus(0)->count();
$consulta2 = Mensaje::whereStatus(0)->count();
$consulta3 = News::whereStatus(0)->count();
```

Ahora para devolver un *ÚNICO* resultado sería del modo siguiente:

```
$status = ["status" => $consulta1 + $consulta2 + $consulta3];
```

Dependiendo de lo que las 3 consultas arrojen, el resultado en pantalla debería lucir mas o menos así:

> {"status":0}

Si ahora quieres establecer una condición basándote en el resultado provisto, entonces deberás hacerlo a través de un condicional de esta forma:

```
if($status["status"] === 0)
{
    //acciones
} else {
    //otras acciones
}
```

**Nota:**

> Revisa a detalle en el primer enlace que te pasé las reglas que se deben cumplir en la creación y contenido de los modelos en Eloquent.

Comment: Brillante @BetaM  funciona a la perfección! grande! ;)